# Plot USA map - big white triangle. FIXED. New: geocode limit of 2500 requests per day

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

When plotting map of USA, I get the map but with a big white triangle in the middle. Anyone sees the same?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggmap)
require(maps)

US <- map_data("usa", region=".")

plot(ggplot(US, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
       geom_polygon() +
       coord_map())
```

[image]

The above problem is fixed.
Now I wan to mark cities on map with number of ads/calls/etc - a data frame of 4900 locations. However, `google` restricts usage to non-business users to 2500 per day. 
Do you know of a more elegant solution other than breaking the DF in smaller (<= 2500) rows data frames, making a `geopoint`, and stitching?

E.g. like that, with pseudodata:

```
state = rep("IL", 2500)
city  = rep("Chicago", 2500)
ads   = rep(15, 2500)


ads_df = data.frame(state,city,ads)
ads_df <- cbind(geocode(as.character(ads_df$city)), ads_df)

state= rep("FL", 2500)
city  = rep("Miami", 2500)
ads   = rep(15, 2500)

ads_df1 = data.frame(state,city,ads)
ads_df1 <- cbind(geocode(as.character(ads_df1$city)), ads_df1)

ads_df = rbind(ads_df,ads_df1)

plot(ggplot(US, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
              geom_polygon(aes(group = group) ) +
              coord_map() + geom_point(data=ads_df, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=ads), color="orange"))
```

Comment: I also see a big white triangle there.

Comment: Please open a new question since your original one is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggmaps` is set up to use `group` for polygons:

```
> plot(ggplot(US, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
+          geom_polygon(aes(group = group)) +
+          coord_map())
```