# geocode/google restricts 2500 requests per day or code run?

Tags: r, google-maps

Building on top of this one:
[Plot USA map - big white triangle. FIXED. New: geocode limit of 2500 requests per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041196/plot-usa-map-big-white-triangle-fixed-new-geocode-limit-of-2500-requests-pe?noredirect=1#comment46327082_29041196)

I want to mark cities on map with number of ads/calls/etc - a data frame of 4900 locations. However, google restricts usage to non-business users to 2500 per day. Or one run? I could successfully run the code more than one time, if I cut my dataset at 2500. What is the rule then?

Anyways. Do you know of a more elegant solution other than breaking the DF in smaller (<= 2500) rows data frames, making a geopoint, and stitching?

E.g. like that, with pseudodata. (Apparently, I could exceed 2500 limit per day, and I ran it 10 times.)

```
state = rep("IL", 2500)
city  = rep("Chicago", 2500)
ads   = rep(15, 2500)

ads_df = data.frame(state,city,ads)
ads_df <- cbind(geocode(as.character(ads_df$city)), ads_df)

state= rep("FL", 2500)
city  = rep("Miami", 2500)
ads   = rep(15, 2500)

ads_df1 = data.frame(state,city,ads)
ads_df1 <- cbind(geocode(as.character(ads_df1$city)), ads_df1)

ads_df = rbind(ads_df,ads_df1)

plot(ggplot(US, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
              geom_polygon(aes(group = group) ) +
              coord_map() + geom_point(data=ads_df, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=ads), color="orange"))
```

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geocodeHERE/index.html geocodeHERE accepts bulk addresses to geocode instead of one at a time. Limit is 10K, but I suspect that it's not enforced...

Comment: If all you need is city/state resolution then you can do it without an API using my `localgeo` pacakge: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/localgeo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete example that also uses a proper US projection:

```
# devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/localgeo")
library(localgeo)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

state <- c(rep("IL", 2500), rep("FL", 2500))
city <- c(rep("Chicago", 2500), rep("Miami", 2500))
ads <- c(rep(15, 2500), rep(15, 2500))

ads_df <- data.frame(state, city, ads, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ads_df <- bind_cols(ads_df, geocode(ads_df$city, ads_df$state))

us <- map_data("state")
us <- fortify(us, region="region")

# for theme_map
devtools::source_gist("33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us, map=us,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region, group=group),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=ads_df,
                      aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=ads), color="orange")
# life's too short for bad projections
gg <- gg + coord_map("albers", lat0=39, lat1=45)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg
```

[image]

Note that this package will not be a full replacement for an API service and is not nearly as forgiving about names as Nokia or Google is. But, it can help when you hit API limits and have fairly decent/clean city names/data.

Comment: Thanks! That is great! I'm wondering if it's possible to add Canada map, since my data are both US and CAN. But it will probably be not practical as the map will be rather small.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that'll let you use a Bing Maps API (500,000 limit in a lifetime). You have to sign up for microsoft marketplace but its free.

```
#Google Maps API limits querys to 2500 per day and fails to geocode smaller towns. So here's a function to geocode using Bing's API. It's also much faster.
geocode <- function( x, verbose=FALSE, service="google", returntype="coordinates", ... ) {
  UseMethod("geocode",x)
}
geocode.default <- function(x,verbose=FALSE, service="google", returntype="coordinates", ...) {
  if( is.na( x ) | gsub(" *", "", x) == ""  ) return(c(NA,NA))
  service <- tolower(service)
  BingMapsKey <- getOption("BingMapsKey")
  if(service=="bing" && is.null(BingMapsKey) ) stop("To use Bing, you must save your Bing Maps API key (obtain at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx) using options(BingMapsKey='mykey').\n")
  construct.geocode.url <- list()
  construct.geocode.url[["google"]] <- function(address, return.call = "json", sensor = "false") {
    root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/"
    u <- paste(root, return.call, "?address=", address, "&sensor=", sensor, sep = "")
    return(URLencode(u))  
  }
  construct.geocode.url[["bing"]] <- function(address, maxResults=1) {
    root <- "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations"
    u <- paste0(root, "?query=", address, "&maxResults=",maxResults,"&key=",BingMapsKey)
    return(URLencode(u))
  }
  if(verbose) message(x,appendLF=FALSE)
  u <- construct.geocode.url[[service]](x)
  doc <- RCurl::getURL(u)
  j <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(doc,simplify = FALSE)
  parse.json <- list()
  parse.json[["google"]] <- function(j) {
    if(j$status=="OK") {
      res <- list()
      if( "coordinates" %in% returntype ) {
        lat <- j$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
        lng <- j$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng
        res$coordinates <- c(lat, lng)
      }
      if( "zip" %in% returntype )  {
        zp <- j$results[[1]]$address_components[[8]]$short_name
        if( j$results[[1]]$address_components[[8]]$types[[1]] != "postal_code" )  warning(paste("Not sure these zips are actually zips.  Type:", j$results[[1]]$address_components[[8]]$types[[1]]) )
        res$zip <- zp
      }
      return( res )
    } else {
      if(j$status=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") warning("Google's geocoding quota appears to have been reached for the day.")
      return(c(NA,NA))
    }
  }
  parse.json[["bing"]] <- function(j) {
    if(j$authenticationResultCode != "ValidCredentials") {
      warning("Your BingMapsKey was not accepted.")
      return(c(NA,NA))
    }
    if(j$statusDescription!="OK") {
      warning("Something went wrong. Bing Maps API return status code ",j$statusCode," - ", j$statusDescription)
      return(c(NA,NA))
    }
    if(j$resourceSets[[1]]$estimatedTotal==0) {
      warning("Didn't find any points")
      return(c(NA,NA))
    }
    if(verbose) message(" - Confidence: ", j$resourceSets[[1]]$resources[[1]]$confidence ,appendLF=FALSE)
    res <- list()
    if( "coordinates" %in% returntype ) {
      crds <- unlist(j$resourceSets[[1]]$resources[[1]]$point$coordinates)
      res$coordinates <- crds
    }
    if( "zip" %in% returntype )  {
      res$zip <- sub( "^.*(\\d{5}-?\\d?\\d?\\d?\\d?).*$", "\\1", j$resourceSets[[1]]$resources[[1]]$address$formattedAddress )
    }
    return( res )
  }
  res <- parse.json[[service]](j)
  if(length(returntype)==1) res <- res[[1]]
  if(verbose) message("\n",appendLF=FALSE)
  return( res )
}

#Vectorize function
geocodeVect <- Vectorize(geocode, vectorize.args="x")

#Batch geocode with Bing
options(BingMapsKey="YourBingAPIkey")

data<-geocodeVect(vector, service="bing", 
                       returntype="coordinates")
data <-as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(data)))
data $location<-rownames(data)
rownames(data)<-NULL
```

Comment: it looks awesome but it returns an error: `Failed to connect to dev.virtualearth.net port 80: Timed out` when I try `geocode("Eiffel tower", verbose=FALSE, service="bing")` (I have a brand new API key). Did the API change ?

Comment: Nevermind it came from this unrelated (and unsolved) issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399895/failed-to-connect-to-url-port-80-timed-out-in-r-how-can-i-solve . I got around it by replacing `doc <- RCurl::getURL(u);j <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(doc,simplify = FALSE)` by `doc = "temp.json";download.file(u,doc);j <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(doc,simplify = FALSE);file.remove(doc)`. Dirty but does the trick. Thanks for the great post.

Comment: Last thing, if you want to have the same output format as `ggmap:geocode`, add this just before the return line : `res <- setNames(data.frame(t(rev(res))),c("lon","lat"))`