# "Failed to connect to "url" port 80: Timed Out" in R, how can I solve?

Tags: r, web, port80

I'm trying to test this code:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population"
urldata <- getURL(url)
```

When I press enter, the R returns:

> ```
> Failed to connect to en.wikipedia.org port 80: Timed out
> ```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I tried you code. On my end, there was no problem.

Comment: on my code theres an error too

Comment: What are you trying to do with this Url?